# ImageView on Top

Tags: android, xml

I have simple problem, I have inserted an Image with 3 TextViews, I want that the ImageView is on Top of the Layout, How Can I do this?

[image: layout screenshot]

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: Use a `FrameLayout`

Comment: Why did you use layout_weight

Comment: Wrap your ImageView with a FrameLayout. Set the weight of the FrameLayout to 1, and it will occupy the space needed. The ImageView will stay on top.

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As a Solution I have written this code and I Add CenterCrop

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

This is the result:
[image: result screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change your LinearLayout for a RelativeLayout (For place your items when you want)
In your RelativeLayout change your orientation to **horizontal**

After it, put your ImageView into a LinearLayout whithout the textViews.
After that, write another LinearLayout for put int the textViews.

It will looks like :

```
RelativeLayout

    LinearLayout
       Image
    /LinearLayout

    LinearLayout
       TextView
       TextView
       ...
    /LinearLayout

/RelativeLayout
```